# How to assign a binary value to mpz_class object

Tags: c++, gmp

I want to assign a binary value to mpz_class object

I have a binary number 10011101111001111100010111000011111010010.

I want  to assign it to value object i.e(mpz_class value)

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you are talking about the GMP library? Then please say so, and post some code.

Comment: You need to describe the **format** of your binary number not it's value. For instance, is it a string? Is it bytes? Is it words? Is it little endian or big endian? You can do all of this if you would only **post some code**. Show us the variable that holds your binary number, show us the variable where you want to assign it to.

Comment: Yes i am talking about GMP Library only sorry..   I have tried with following code but the value of value variable when i printed using gmp_printf is coming something different, so i thought i should try by assigning binary value, so calculated a binary value of 1356396726226 and i was trying to assign but not able to do so..so please help me                                                unsigned long int intValue = 1356396726226;                                                  mpz_class temp;
mpz_init2(value.get_mpz_t(), 125);
mpz_set_ui(value.get_mpz_t(),intValue );

Comment: I think 1356396726226 is too big for a long int. You are going to have to try a different way. See my updated answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, whether it is what you need I cannot say because you are still not describing your problem very well

```
mpz_class value("1356396726226", 10);
```

Here's another way

```
mpz_class value("10011101111001111100010111000011111010010", 2);
```

Both these examples use the mpz_class constructor that takes a string. Maybe that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I writing this in the hope that anyone finding the solution to this will have better option to achieve the described functionality.

The GMP provides the functionality to export and import the mpz structure into the binary and they are:

```
mpz_import(mpz_t rop, size_t count, int order, size_t size, int endian, size_t nails, const void *op)
mpz_export(void *rop, size_t *countp, int order, size_t size, int endian, size_t nails, const mpz_t op)
```

They are better described in [Integer Import and Export](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html).
Typically you export your mpz_t structure using mpz_export command and it will output the binary array in the format of W|W|W|W|W where W being group of binary bytes that you specify as Word. The order param specifies the endianess of the binary in terms of Word and the endian param specifies the endianess inside of the W(group of binary bytes).

So in above case, if we have the binary representation of a number in

```
const char num[100];
// assuming some initialization of num from may be inbound network packet?
```

We can create the mpz_t using the binary by

```
mpz_t res; mpz_init(res);
mpz_import(res, 100, -1, 1, -1, 0, num);
```

assuming the bytes we have are in little endian with size of the Word being 1 byte.